# Is there a static checker for JAX-RS annotations?

Tags: java, jax-rs, static-analysis

I just started using JAX-RS annotations for client-server communication (using Resteasy + RestyGWT). From time to time, I run into a problem at runtime that I think could be spotted at compile time. Recent examples are forgetting a @JsonCreator annotation at a constructor or having a mismatch between upper and lower case in the property name generated from the getter and the one specified with @JsonProperty for the constructor parameter. I noticed both of these only when I tested the service after building the application. So I was wondering if there is some tool to do these checks at compile time. Something like a FindBugs or Checkstyle plugin would be great, as we are already using these tools for all sorts of static analysis.